# migration works but still get Format of the initialization string error on running

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

First I have checked all the answers with the similar errors and cannot find an answer...

and I have also used https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/ to check my connection string.

connection string is as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuthServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The same entry is in all projects in the solution.

The app that uses the connection is a webapi app.
When I run code first migration, the database "DefaultConnection" is successfully created.
I am using sql server 2012
I can see the database in sql server

so next I publish the app to localhost
localhost uses the network service user in the app pool
I have added network service in sql server 2012 as a login

after i publish the app to localhost I restart iis server

then I go to postman and create a request to register a user

I get the following error
    "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.",

why would migration work but post man cannot work?

text of error is below

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection
>   connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1
>   interceptionContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput
>   input)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.<ValidateUserName>d__14.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CreateAsync>d__73.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__79.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   AuthServer.API.Controllers.AccountController.d__20.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\chris\source\repos\AngularJSAuthentication\AuthServer.API\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line
>   335\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}

Comment: try to add `<clear />` above `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString...` this will clear all stored connectionStrings and add the new one.

Comment: The connection string looks fine. Can you show us how you are initialising the context and how you are passing the connection string. Also, can you please post the text of the error message, not an incomplete image.

Comment: its literally the vs2017 template for webapi with individual authentication. I just edited to use SQLEXPRESS instance... public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

Comment: just a note.. when i create a new solution and add a web api template project... I can get it to work straight off with sqlexpress.... i guess its just that this is an old solution with a few old projects in it (all marked as unloaded).. this must be affecting the behaviour